# Relative Minima and Maxima and Graph $f''(x)$ using below graph $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

Let f be a function that is continuous for all $x$ and differentiable for all $x$ other than $0$.
figure below is the graph of its derivative $f'(x)$ 
(a) What are the critical numbers?
Where do any relative maxima or relative minima occur?
Explain.
(b) Assuming that $f(0) = 1$, graph a hypothetical function$f(x)$
that satisfies the given conditions.
(c) Graph $f''(x)$.

I know the critical numbers are where the $f'(x)$ is crossing the x axis, however I have problems with finding the relative minima and maxima and graphing the $f''(x)$. An explanation would be appreciated.

[image: Figure]

Comment: There will also be a critical point at $x=0$ since $f'$ is not defined there, yet $f$ is assumed to be defined for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about maxima and minima intuitively: when a maximum occurs, the function will be increasing up until the max and then will begin decreasing after the max.  This implies that f'(just before max)>0 because if f'(x)>0 ==> f(x) is increasing.  The opposite will be true for minima: namely f'(x) will be negative just before the min (such that the function is decreasing to the min) and positive after the min (such that the function increases out of the min).  Therefore, you are correct to say that the CP of f(x) occur when f'(x) crosses the x axis, but when f'(x) goes from positive to negative, you will have a max, and when f'(x) goes from negative to positive, you will have a min.

For graphing f''(x), just think of f'(x) as the plot of some random function, say g(x).  If you can plot f'(x) given f(x), you should be able to apply the same logic and graph g'(x) given g(x) (in this case since g(x)=f'(x), g'(x)=f''(x)).

Comment: $f'$ does not *have* to cross the axis for a critical point. The above function $f$, if it is defined and continuous everywhere, and has derivative as pictured in the graph, will have a local minimum at $x=0$ even though $f'$ does not cross the axis there.

Comment: True, I should have been more clear: I was referencing when f'(x) exists.